# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

ASP.Net MVC 4

I am trying to populate a list of Countries (data from Country table in DB) in a dropdownlist. I get the following error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]', but this dictionary requires a model    item of type 'BIReport.Models.Country'.
```

I am new to ASP.Net MVC and I don't understand that error. What I feel is what Index method is returning doesn't match with the model that I am using in the View.

Model::

```
namespace BIReport.Models
{
  public partial class Country
  {
    public int Country_ID { get; set; }
    public string Country_Name { get; set; }
    public string Country_Code { get; set; }
    public string Country_Acronym { get; set; }
  }

 }
```

Controller::

```
   public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private CorpCostEntities _context;

    public HomeController()
    {
        _context = new CorpCostEntities();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var countries = _context.Countries.Select(arg => arg.Country_ID).ToList();
        ViewData["Country_ID"] = new SelectList(countries);
        return View(countries);
    }

}
```

View::

```
@model BIReport.Models.Country
<label>
Country @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country_ID, ViewData["Country_ID"] as SelectList)
</label>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting CountryIDs, therefore you will have a list of integers passed into the view.

I think you really want something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var countries = _context.Countries.ToList();
    ViewData["Country_ID"] = new SelectList(countries, "Country_ID", "Country_Name");
    return View();
}
```

I'm not really sure why you have single country as a model for your view.

Update:

I'm still not sure why the model is a country, if you are just going to post the ID of the selected country you don't necessarily need a model at all (or just have an integer). This will be just fine though:

View

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Country

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country_ID, ViewData["Country_ID"] as SelectList)
```

Comment: I have a country table, where there are many other columns then the Country_Name. That's why I had the Country as a model. No idea if that is wrong. Btw, in your case how would the View code look like? Sorry for asking this.

Comment: So your view is supposed to be a table consisting of multiple countries?

Comment: I am not sure how to say it in MVC context, but I am trying to show a dropdownlist on my Index page with a list of countries. So I have a table called Country where-

Comment: namespace BIReport.Models
{
    public partial class Country
    {
        public int Country_ID { get; set; }
        public string Country_Name { get; set; }
        public string Country_Code { get; set; }
        public string Country_Acronym { get; set; }
    }
    
}

Comment: Nevermind, I thought you were talking about html table for some reason :P I'll update in a sec

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in line 1 of your view. change it like this :

```
@model IEnumerable<BIReport.Models.Country>
```

also there is no need to pass the model to view if you already did it by :

```
ViewData["Country_ID"] = new SelectList(countries);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say @model BIReport.Models.Country it means your view is expecting a model consisting  single country details. On the contrary you need a list of countries to be displayed in the drop-down list. Hence you should tell the view to look for a list of country details instead.
Therefore @model IEnumerable.